# Naming MySQL table column

Tags: php, mysql

I am encountering one little problem here:

I am entering one MySQL query through PHP. I have checked the connection works fine and looks like the following:

```
INSERT INTO table (q1,q2,q3) VALUES ('".$_POST['Q1']."', '".$_POST['Q2']."'...)
```

then when I change the query to the following, there is an error:

```
INSERT INTO table (q1,q2,q3-1) VALUES ('".$_POST['Q1']."', '".$_POST['Q2']."'...)
```

The following error appears:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-1) VALUES ('N', 'asdfasdf', '' )' at line 1

Now, I am thinking, is it because:

1. I name the table column as 'q3-1'
2. or any other problem?

Would it be okay if I change it to q3_1 instead?

Comment: Switch hyphen with underscore when naming columns. Also, remember that MySQL has a list of reserved words, so it's good practice to wrap column and table names within ticks, like so: `\`column_name\``

Comment: q3-1 looks like an operation to sql. It is best to use q3_1 or another naming convention.

Comment: column is often hard to spell.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have error in your second query because of `q3-1`. It should be in quotes :

```
INSERT INTO table (q1,q2,`q3-1`) VALUES ('".$_POST['Q1']."', '".$_POST['Q2']."'...)
```

Comment: Read the question is sometimes a good thing : `Now, I am thinking, is it because : I name the table coloumn as 'q3-1'`

Answer (score 4):

If you put backticks ` around the field names, it should be OK

ie:

```
  INSERT INTO table (`q1`,`q2`,`q3-1`) ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Use backticks.  Look into [PDO](http://us.php.net/pdo).

```
INSERT INTO table (q1,q2,`q3-1`) 
VALUES ('".$_POST['Q1']."', '".$_POST['Q2']."'...)
```

Answer (score 1):

escape the columns name with backtick ( **`** )

```
INSERT INTO table (`q1`, `q2`, `q3-1`) 
VALUES ('".$_POST['Q1']."', '".$_POST['Q2']."'...)
```

but this statement is vulnerable with `SQL Injection`. Try using it with **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**

ex.)

```
<?php
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO table (`q1`, `q2`, `q3-1`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['Q1']);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['Q2']);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['Q3']);

$stmt->execute();

?>
```